# Unicode character class escape without one character

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want to replace all [`Separator`](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table) category [characters](https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) except for space (`U+20`) in a string with a "?". I can do it using [Unicode character class escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Unicode_character_class_escape) and replacing the space with itself:

```
const escapeRegex = /\p{Separator}/gu;
' foo\xA0 bar\u1680'.replace(escapeRegex, (c) => c === ' ' ? ' ' : '?');
// ' foo? bar?'
```

But surely calling a function for every space is inefficient. Most of my strings won't have any `Separator`s (besides spaces) at all and space is the most common character in normal text.

I can do this with a negative lookahead

```js
const escapeRegex = /(?! )(\p{Separator})/gu;
' foo\xA0 bar\u1680'.replace(escapeRegex, '?');
```

but again, this seems less efficient than just reducing the set of characters in the character class that need to be checked for, or is the regex engine smart enough to optimize this lookahead into the character class? Is there a better way?

My question is similar to [JavaScript regex character exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777728/javascript-regex-character-exclusion) but it's not the same because I'm not using a character class `[]`, I'm using a Unicode character class `\p{}`.

Comment: Use character class subtraction, `.replace(/[\p{Separator}-- ]/gv, '?')` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76287186/3832970)).

Comment: ...or `[^ \P{Separator}]` if you want to refrain from using `v`.

Comment: If you don't trust the other suggestions you can always use a negative look behind `\p{Separator}(?<![ ])` or just use the resultant `[\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028-\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000]` which is slightly slower.

Comment: @sln in [my actual code](https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/blob/646a0efc289ece9aa24f56ff8b4cf9d50074a2cc/src/generators/python.ts#L385) I'm doing `\p{Other}` as well. I simplified for the question.

Comment: These are all the Unicode characters `[^\p{NChar}\p{Cc}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}\p{Co}]`  149,186. What is it you're tring to do ? And separator is of course `\p{Zs}` short.

Comment: I'm writing javascript code (see link in my previous comment) that [generates Python code](https://curlconverter.com/) and I need to convert unprintable characters (`/\p{Separator}|\p{Other}/gu`, except space, based on [PEP 3138](https://peps.python.org/pep-3138/#specification)) into their backslash escapes like `\n` or `\u1680`.

Comment: Try `[\p{Zs}\p{NChar}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}\p{Co}](?<![ ])`

Comment: I want to [escape](https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/blob/646a0efc/src/generators/python.ts#L403-L416) [all](https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/blob/646a0efc/src/generators/python.ts#L424-L431) control codes. `\p{Other}` is `\p{C}` which includes all the control codes. You can [see](https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/blob/646a0efc/src/generators/python.ts#L385) I'm backslash-escaping `/"|\\|\p{C}|\p{Z}/gu` characters. The code already does what I want, I just want it to be more efficient by not checking for space in the regex.

Comment: `\p{C}` misses about 170 chars that `[\p{NChar}\p{Cc}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}\p{Co}]` correctly picks up. As fot the alternations, they should be combined into a class. Therefore this `/["\\\p{NChar}\p{Cc}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}\p{Co}\p{Zs}](?<![ ])/gu`

Comment: Yeah, I think the one in the last comment is the best bet. I'm working through it in this app, complex.

Comment: So it's the reverse `\p{C}` has 170 more characters than `[\p{NChar}\p{Cc}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}\p{Co}]`. These extra characters are actual letters in various languages you probably wouldn't want to suppress. I wouldn't trust the Uni-Consortium on this though. I was using the UCD database for query's. Good luck!

Comment: @sln "These extra characters are actual letters" no they're not, they are "control characters". The [difference](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#GC_Values_Table) between `\p{Cc}\p{Cn}\p{Cs}\p{Co}` and `\p{C}` is `\p{Cf}`, aka `\p{Format}`. None of them are actually letters...

Comment: You can do `curl -s https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt | grep ";Cf;"` and see that none of them are letters.

Comment: @InSync what if I have two categories? `[^ \P{Separator}\P{Other}]` doesn't work because the two mutually exclusive categories cancel each other out

Comment: Use a branch: `[^ \P{Separator}]|\p{Other}`. If you're dealing with a time-sensitive product, this might affects backtracking a little bit.

Comment: I believe the `\p{Cf}` is not in the same style as `[\p{Cc}\p{Cf}\p{Cn}\p{Co}\p{Cs}]` as each of the 170 characters are a mix of miscellaneous  joiners, tags and letter enhancements/modifiers. Example this is an Emoji `0E007D TAG RIGHT CURLY BRACKET` https://emojipedia.org/tag-right-curly-bracket/. \p{Format} seems ancient. Here is a jpeg of the U+codes/char/name of all 170. https://imgur.com/8dtY5Li (download to see the larger image, 1,170k) w`hich you probably already know. Removing \p{Cf} characters will affect the adjacent rendering.

Comment: Also the most performative way is to use the negative assertion _after_ the class matches. Don't use alternations. These property classes are a single function call where each has binary tables that return immediately with pass or fail. They do not do regex stuff like ranges and alternations. Avoid regex overhead, alternations negative classes, etc. The negative assertion is a single check _only_ done if any of the properties matched. So thats not an issue. And make the assertion without using the class (done for illustrative purposes only) `(?<! )`

Comment: I could be wrong about \p{Cf} don't know. For my own interest I'm going to dig into this.

Comment: @InSync you're a genius. I wish the question wasn't closed as a duplicate because I would accept your answer as an answer, but it doesn't work for the question mine is supposedly a duplicate of.

Comment: @sln `\p{C}` is identical to `[\p{Cc}\p{Cf}\p{Cn}\p{Co}\p{Cs}]`. I have no clue what you're talking about or what the regexes you've been suggesting to me are supposed to accomplish or what your screenshot is supposed to show me. Are you schizophrenic?

Comment: Yeah, like I said before if you include `\p{Cf}` 170 characters in any property you reference for exclusion, you will mess up the formatting of the document. These are not control codes ! : `­؀؁؂؃؄؅؜۝܏࢐࢑࣢᠎​‌‍‎‏‪‫‬‭‮⁠⁡⁢⁣⁤⁦⁧⁨⁩⁪⁫⁬⁭⁮⁯￹￺￻`

Comment: You could exclude the formatting like you exclude the space:  `/[\\"\p{C}\p{Zs}](?<![ \p{Cf}])/gu` Last I'm gonna say.